# Context and Fragments on orientation change

Tags: android

I'm using the Fragment compatibility package.

In my Fragment in onAttach, I keep a `Context` reference.

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.w(logTag, "Activity is: " + activity);
    mContext = activity;
    Log.w(logTag, "mContext is: " + mContext); // <-- Breakpoint here
}
```

later on, I use the context

```
private String loadExampleSuccessXML () {
    try {
        AssetManager assets = this.mContext.getAssets(); // <-- Breakpoint here
        //Other Stuff
```

When I change orientation, onAttach seems to store the new Context but when I get to `loadExampleSuccessXML`, `mContext` is null.

I have breakpoints after `mContext` has been saved in onAttach, and at `mContext.getAsssets()`.

When I first run the app the debugger shows the value of mContext:

In `onAttach(), mContext [MyActivity] (id=830010419632)`

In `loadExampleSuccessXML(), mContext   [MyActivity]  (id=830010419632)`

But then after a config change

In `onAttach(), mContext    [MyActivity]  (id=830010565472)`

In `loadExampleSuccessXML(), mContext   null`

I can't understand why. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide some more detail as to why you need to maintain a reference to the context? This has never been a requirement for our apps at least and has been shown (albeit not in your case from the code you have posted) to be the prime culprit in Android memory leaks...

If you need to maintain an aspect of a previous activity's state then I would suggest using `onSavedInstanceState()`. Here you can pass through some simple properties (like the id of an item I last selected in a list). The Manifest config fix is usually the wrong approach despite it's prevalence on help sites such as this. You probably don't want that.

Finally, look into using `setRetainInstance(true)`...again, in our experience this is quite the dangerous method if used incorrectly! That's probably just us but it does have some bugs with the recent `android.support.v4.*` libraries at least. When set to `true` this ensures that the fragment is never destroyed (i.e. `onDestroy()` is called) but is simply attached and detached as the owing activity is destroyed on rotation and recreated. It will sort your problem but do have a read of the documentation around it's usage...some of the side affects are quite subtle.

Comment: I need to be able to open an asset. For this, I need a Context. I would just use getActivity() but it returns null so I was trying a workaround. I guess this is the root cause of a number of these sorts of issues I'm having

Comment: I'm not calling `getAssets()` from `onAttach`. The call to `loadExampleSuccessXML` is made from an onClickListener of a View in my layout. Surely the Activity is running by then?

Comment: OK. Move the call to ````getAssets()```` into ````onActivityCreated()```` and move back to using getActivity(). At the point of onActivityCreated you can be sure that the activity is running under a context and you will not get an NPE. :)

Comment: Sorry Mike. All out of suggestions. I would implement the ````...getAssets()```` in the ````onActivityCreated```` as mentioned above but I assume that didn't work? Failing that, test it with ````getApplicationContext().getAssets()````. You shouldn't really need to nuke it like that but essentially you need a context and don't really care whether it is the one the parent activity is running under or the container... so perhaps acceptable.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help. I'm just really confused why `getActivity()` is returning null after `onAttach()`. After reading the docs, this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered. I think this is a symptom of a deeper problem. I've been trying to keep references to Fragments and trying to access them after a config change (after they've been detached). Silly me. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

As my experiences, you should handle orientation changing:

```
<activity
    android:name="com..."
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

References:

- [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).